# IdentityServer and Session Storage

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

Apologies if this sounds a bit stupid, but I'm just experimenting with a javascript client using oidc-client.js connecting to identityserver 4. 
The server creates a token and then sends it to the client where oidc stores it in session storage(as i understand it). 
Supposing you referenced an external javascript library on a cdn somewhere which got compromised somehow. What's to stop that compromised js accessing the token in the session data and giving an attacker access to whatever you're trying to secure with the token.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing at all. Don't use CDN-hosted libs for anything you actually care about the security of. Even with HTTP-only cookies a targeted attack is possible. While you're at it don't let NPM anywhere near anything you care about the security of as the potential exposure to malware is terrifying.

All in my opinion.